# Firefox input box treats decimal min as increment

Tags: html, firefox, input

I have noticed that Firefox (unlike any other browser) is treating the min=".1" tag as the required decimal rather than the minimum number that can be accepted in a input type="number" box like this one:

`<input id="numberInput" type="number" min=".1" value="1">`

If I set it to 1 or any other whole number, a red box will appear around the input (implying the input is invalid). But if the input is changed to 1.1 or any other number ending in .1 (such as 2.1 or 10.1) it removes the red box, implying that this value checks out.

**[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rLr3jxd/1/)**

Anyone know what is going on here?

Before you tell me, I do know that I can add step="any" to fix this "problem", but that seems like it should be unnecessary to do given that MIN is just supposed to set the floor on the input based on the HTML5 standard as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)